# What should I use the extra space on my SDCard for in addition to ReadyDrive?

Tags: windows-7, readyboost

I use ReadyBoost to increase the performance of my Windows 7 x64 with 2GB of RAM with noticeable results.

I have a high speed SD card capable of 100Mb/s with a 16Gb capacity.  Ready drive seems to only use 4GB of it.

Can I partition my SD card so I can use more space for readydrive purposes?  Should I put my page file on the extra space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the drive with the exFAT file system and use all 16GBs of it for ReadyBoost.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost
"Windows 7 also supports the new exFAT file system"
"Windows 7 allows up to eight devices for a maximum of 256 GB of additional memory,[5] with up to 32 GB on a single storage device"

I realize this doesn't answer your question of what else to use it for, sorry. If you use whole drive encryption you could store your key(s) there.